# Can't install Capybara-Webkit on Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qt, debian, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am currently trying to install Capybara-Webkit on a rails 3.2 app. Everytime I try to install the gem I get the following output. I am on Debian unstable.

```
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/james/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''
Command 'qmake -spec linux-g++' failed


Gem files will remain installed in /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@ho/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/james/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@ho/gems/capybara-webkit-1.0.0/./gem_make.out
```

I've installed `libqtwebkit-dev` via apt, as well as `qtcreator`. I still get these errors and I'm at my wits end.

Has anyone else come across this issue with debian? It's been a long day so i'm likely missing some information. Please let me know if there is any more info I can provide.

Comment: Do you have qmake installed?

Comment: So, I do ````sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake```` and it says that it is already installed. However, when I do ````which qmake```` nothing returns.

Answer (score 8):

My initial guess was that the gem's build script couldn't properly locate my qmake for whatever reason and I think that might have had something to do with it as doing `export QMAKE=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4` seemed to resolve the issue.

If you are a debian user and cannot get this gem to install, try giving these steps a shot. I've not tested out which ones are not required on a clean system but after doing all of them I was able to install the gem.

1. `sudo apt-get install libqtwebkit-dev qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui qmake-qt4`
2. `export QMAKE=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4`
3. `gem install capybara-webkit`

That seems to have done the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks, tho has to install a couple of additional libraries too: qt4-qmake libqt5webkit5-dev qtquick1-5-dev qtlocation5-dev qtsensors5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev libxslt1-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libsqlite3-dev

Comment: In my case, the first option (installing `libqtwebkit-dev`) alone seemed to do the trick -- that pulled in all the other needed dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04(LTS):

- sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake
- sudo apt-get install libqtwebkit-dev

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 14.04 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The qmake-qt4 package has been rename qt4-qmake  ;) and is include by the others. 
So:

```
sudo apt-get install libqtwebkit-dev qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```